# How solve that error: At present, only @Result types that are discovered by the domain entity package scanning can be mapped

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using spring boot v2.0.0.M6 with neo4j as database, but when i try to make a @QueryResul i see this error: *At present, only @Result types that are discovered by the domain entity package scanning can be mapped.*

**this is the repository**

```
`

    package com.dariel.sna.repositories;

    import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
    import com.dariel.sna.domain.Character;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.QueryResult;
    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;


    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "characters", path = "characters")
    public interface CharacterRepository extends Neo4jRepository {

        Character findByName(@Param("name") String name);

        @Query("match r=(:Character)-[:INTERACTS]-(:Character) return r")
        Collection graph();

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //centralidad de grado
        @Query("MATCH (c:Character {name:{0}}) RETURN  c.name AS name, size( (c)-[:INTERACTS]-() ) AS degree")
        DegreeCentralityData getCharacterDegreeCentralityByName(String name);

        @QueryResult
        public class DegreeCentralityData {

            private String name;
            private Long degree;
        }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
```

**This is the node entity**

```
    package com.dariel.sna.domain;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;


    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @NodeEntity(label = "Character")
    public class Character {

       @GraphId private Long id;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private String name;

        @Relationship(type = "INTERACTS", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
        private  List interactions = new ArrayList();



        private Character() {
            // Empty constructor required as of Neo4j API 2.0.5
        };

        public Character(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Collection getInteractions() {
            return interactions;
        }

        public void addInteraction(Interaction interaction) {
            this.interactions.add(interaction);
        }


    }
```

**this is the error page**

```
    org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Error mapping to ad-hoc class com.dariel.sna.repositories.CharacterRepository$DegreeCentralityData.  At present, only @Result types that are discovered by the domain entity package scanning can be mapped.
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.SingleUseEntityMapper.resolveClassInfoFor(SingleUseEntityMapper.java:96) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.SingleUseEntityMapper.setPropertiesOnEntity(SingleUseEntityMapper.java:85) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.SingleUseEntityMapper.map(SingleUseEntityMapper.java:80) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.CustomResultConverter.convert(CustomResultConverter.java:54) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.lambda$and$0(ResultProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:166) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.doExecute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:80) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:51) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:570) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:554) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.getCharacterDegreeCentralityByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.dariel.sna.services.SnaService.characterDegreCentralityByName(SnaService.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.dariel.sna.services.SnaService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$62c75dd1.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685) ~[spring-aop-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.dariel.sna.services.SnaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f8df0cd6.characterDegreCentralityByName() ~[classes/:na]
        at com.dariel.sna.controller.SnaController.characterDegreCentralityByName(SnaController.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

**this is pom.xml file**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.dariel</groupId>
<artifactId>SNA-Springboot-neo4j</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
</parent>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--        dependencias para swagger2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For use in testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved. I moved the @QueryResult class to com.dariel.sna.domain (package that contain all entities class). Then modify the query to return a node and the value of DegreeCentrality and it worked perfectly

This are the codes with the changes

```
    package com.dariel.sna.domain;


    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.QueryResult;


    @QueryResult
    public class Centrality {
        private Character node;
        private double score;


        public Character getNode() {
            return node;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }


    }
```

```
    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "characters", path = "characters")
    public interface CharacterRepository extends Neo4jRepository {

        //Medidas de centralidad
        @Query("MATCH (node:Character {name:{0}}) RETURN  node, size( (node)-[:INTERACTS]-() ) AS score")
        Centrality findCharacterDegreeCentralityByName(String name);
    }
```